# search through JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm a JSON and PHP noob, and need some help! I've got some json, and want to search by `user` with _GET, and return all the info about that user.

JSON:

```
{
Shawn Taylor: {
  user: "Shawn Taylor",
  email: "email@example.com",
  phone: "604-123-4567"
  },
John Smith: {
  user: "John Smith",
  email: "email2@example.com",
  phone: "604-123-4569"
  }
```

FORM:

```
<form method="get">
  <input name="find" />
  <button type="submit">Find</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (!empty($_GET['find'])){
  $find = ($_GET['find']);
  $data_url = 'data.json';
  $data_json = file_get_contents($data_url);
  $data_array = json_decode($data_json, true);
  echo $data_array['user'];
  echo $data_array['email'];
  echo $data_array['phone'];
```

I thought this should work, but no such luck. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Where does the `foreach` loop mentioned in the questions title come in? can't see it in the code you posted...

Comment: Indeed where is the `foreach`? In your PHP you don't use `$find`. Note that you have a 2 dimensional array, not a 1 dimensional one.

Comment: You need something like array_search or similar, or you have to use a loop to iterate through the array.

Comment: bah - title was from old unasked question that I forgot to rename! sorry guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to locate it with the `$find` key.

Try that (look at the 4 last lines) :

```
if (!empty($_GET['find'])){
  $find = ($_GET['find']);
  $data_url = 'data.json';
  $data_json = file_get_contents($data_url);
  $data_array = json_decode($data_json, true);

  $user = $data_array[$find];
  echo $user['user'];
  echo $user['email'];
  echo $user['phone'];
}
```

Comment: its called being tired ;)

Answer (score 0):

You never use $find.

```
if (isset($data_array[$find])) {
    $user = $data_array[$find];
    echo $user['user'];
    echo $user['email';
}
```